# Combined Strings and sum numeric two multidimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, php-7

I have below two arrays with strings and numbers,

I want to keep only one strings header and sum numeric value from each key value with another array.

I have tried many of the solutions available online but nothing found as required.

```
$array1 = 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Out Of Warranty
            [1] => Total Orders
            [2] => Total Qty
            [3] => Canceled Orders
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Today<br/>(04-26-2020)
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Yesterday<br/>(04-25-2020)
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => This Week<br/>(04-20-2020 - 04-26-2020)
            [1] => 22
            [2] => 39
            [3] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Last Week<br/>(04-13-2020 - 04-19-2020)
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => This Month<br/>(04-01-2020 - 04-26-2020)
            [1] => 29
            [2] => 46
            [3] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => This Year<br/>(01-01-2020 - 04-26-2020)
            [1] => 30
            [2] => 47
            [3] => 0
        )

)

$array2 = 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Out Of Warranty
            [1] => Total Orders
            [2] => Total Qty
            [3] => Canceled Orders
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Today<br/>(04-24-2020)
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 10
            [3] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Yesterday<br/>(04-23-2020)
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => This Week<br/>(04-20-2020 - 04-24-2020)
            [1] => 51
            [2] => 51
            [3] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Last Week<br/>(04-13-2020 - 04-19-2020)
            [1] => 31
            [2] => 31
            [3] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => This Month<br/>(04-01-2020 - 04-24-2020)
            [1] => 93
            [2] => 93
            [3] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => This Year<br/>(01-01-2020 - 04-24-2020)
            [1] => 1281
            [2] => 1281
            [3] => 1
        )

)
```

Expected output as Strings should be use only once and numbers should be added to each other.

For example output should be 6 index i.e sum of 6 index from array1 and array2 -

```
[6] => Array
            (
                [0] => This Year<br/>(01-01-2020 - 04-26-2020)
                [1] => 1311
                [2] => 1328
                [3] => 1
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your arrays are always sorted in the same order:

```
$newItems = [];
foreach ($array1 as $key => $item) {
    $newItems[] = [
        $item[0],
        $item[1] + $array2[$key][1],
        $item[2] + $array2[$key][2],
        $item[3] + $array2[$key][3],
    ];
}
```

If keys in arrays are in distinct orders:

```
$newItems = [];
foreach ($array1 as $item) {
    $name = $item[0];
    $newItems[$name] = $item;
}
foreach ($array2 as $item) {
    $name = $item[0];
    $newItems[$name][1] += $item[1];
    $newItems[$name][2] += $item[2];
    $newItems[$name][3] += $item[3];
}
// apply array_values to get 0-indexed array
$newItems = array_values($newItems);
```

Comment: but while using 1st solution its giving output `[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Out Of Warranty
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
        )` which causing 0 index label empty

Comment: So, check if key is 0 and not add / skip values, you can do it, __right__?

Answer (score 0):

Only iterate the elements that are necessary for your summing logic.  Using 2 loops will be the most concise and deliberate way to sum columns `[1]`, `[2]`, and `[3]`.

You can create a new output array, but merely adding the second array values to the first affords a simpler addition-assignment syntax.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/T2Gp3))

```
for ($i = 1, $size = count($array2); $i < $size; ++$i) {  // don't iterate [0] subarray (headers)
    for ($col = 1; $col <= 3; ++$col) {  // don't iterate [0] element (name)
        $array1[$i][$col] += $array2[$i][$col];
    }
}
var_export($array1);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Out Of Warranty',
    1 => 'Total Orders',
    2 => 'Total Qty',
    3 => 'Canceled Orders',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Today<br/>(04-26-2020)',
    1 => 11,
    2 => 11,
    3 => 0,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Yesterday<br/>(04-25-2020)',
    1 => 7,
    2 => 7,
    3 => 0,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'This Week<br/>(04-20-2020 - 04-26-2020)',
    1 => 73,
    2 => 90,
    3 => 0,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Last Week<br/>(04-13-2020 - 04-19-2020)',
    1 => 38,
    2 => 38,
    3 => 0,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => 'This Month<br/>(04-01-2020 - 04-26-2020)',
    1 => 122,
    2 => 139,
    3 => 0,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    0 => 'This Year<br/>(01-01-2020 - 04-26-2020)',
    1 => 1311,
    2 => 1328,
    3 => 1,
  ),
)
```